# How to receive more than one values from the backend via observables

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-event-emitter

i have the below posted service, this service connects to the backend and as a response from the backend i expect to two values `x1` abd `x2`
i would like to know how can i modfiy the code below so to be able to receive two values

**code**:

```
public startWebService(fieldGeometry) {
var endpointURL = 
this.buildEndpointURLForLIDARWebService(fieldGeometry);
return this.httpClient.get(endpointURL)
  .subscribe((responseFromBackend)=>{
    {x1,x2} = responseFromBackend;
});
}
```

**update**

the response is from python code and the invoked webservice will return two values let's say x1 and x2.

Comment: Please share sample API response as well to understand the problem better.

Comment: @MohitKhandelwal it is not clear to me what you are asking for.i added an example/code to the question.please clarify

Comment: What is value of `responseFromBackend` variable ?

Comment: @MohitKhandelwal i expect to recieve two values as a result from the communication with the backend

Comment: you want to receive two emits from a single request?

Comment: Does one of us understood you correctly and is the answer helpful?

Comment: @FlorianN. would you please read the update section i added

Comment: Actually I never worked with python so I don´t know how the response looks like. Maybe you can do a `.subscribe(console.log)` and post the response here. I can´t image the values come seperated...

Comment: @FlorianN. .subscribe(console.log) is not allowed the ide highight it with red

Comment: It is allowed. Just replace everything in your subscription just with `console.log`. No arrow-function or something like that. `return this.httpClient.get(endpointURL).subscribe(console.log)`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get the response from your backend as a JSON-object, so an object of key-value-pairs. So you can acces these attributes with their key. You don´t need to "map" them to an extra object. Because Angular is using TypeScript I would recommend to declare an interface of your object, here is an exmaple:

```
export interface MyObject {
    x1: number;
    x2: number;
}
```

When you then modify your request a little bit, you can access these values in the subscription. To say TS which attributes the response has, use your interface. And if I understand you correctly, you want to save the response in a variable of your class, so declare it first (you need the undefined or null since the http-client work asynchronous and when the page loads the response may need a bit of time):

```
myObject: MyObject | undefined | null;
```

And then in your method you subscribe to the observable, which is the return type of http-client, and save the data in your myObject variable:

```
public startWebService(url: string): void {
    this.httpClient.get<MyObject>(url)
        .subscribe(data => {
            myObject.x1= data.x1;
            myObject.x2= data.x2;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your service code as below to receive two space separated values from backend:

```js
public startWebService(fieldGeometry) {
  var endpointURL = this.buildEndpointURLForLIDARWebService(fieldGeometry);
  this.httpClient.get(endpointURL).subscribe((responseFromBackend)=>{
    result = {x1: null, x2: null};
    result.x1, result.x2 = responseFromBackend.split(' ');  // assuming values are space separated
    return result;
  });
}
```

Comment: would you please read the update section i added. it is not a space separated values